# mysql if not null query not running

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some issues with validating duplicate entries in mysql instead of returning link related to already shortened record it creates a new one, any idea why this is occurring? Here is the code

```
$url = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes(trim($_REQUEST['cf_url'])) : trim($_REQUEST['cf_url']);

function remove_http($url) {
   $disallowed = array('http://', 'https://');
   foreach($disallowed as $d) {
      if(strpos($url, $d) === 0) {
         return str_replace($d, '', $url);
      }
   }
   return $url;
}
$id = rand(10000,99999);  
$short = base_convert($id, 20, 36);

$short_url = $short;
$private_url = md5($short);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ' . DB_TABLE . ' WHERE original_url = ".mysql_real_escape_string(remove_http($url))."");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($num_rows > 0) {

$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ' . DB_TABLE . ' WHERE original_url = ".mysql_real_escape_string(remove_http($url))."");
$object = mysql_fetch_assoc($results);
echo "http://" . BASE_HREF . $object['short_url'];

} else {

mysql_query('LOCK TABLES ' . DB_TABLE . ' WRITE;');
mysql_query('INSERT INTO ' . DB_TABLE . ' (original_url, short_url, private_url, created_on, created_by) VALUES ("' .mysql_real_escape_string(remove_http($url)) . '", "' . $short_url . '", "' . $private_url . '", "' . time() . '", "' . mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) . '")');
mysql_query('UNLOCK TABLES');

echo "http://" . BASE_HREF . $short_url;
}


mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your query might be failing at 1st instance in below code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ' . DB_TABLE . 
' WHERE original_url = ".mysql_real_escape_string(remove_http($url))."");
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Because you will have original_url as `string` value so you should pass with single/double quotes , try with below code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_TABLE .
" WHERE original_url = '".mysql_real_escape_string(remove_http($url))."'") 
or die("Error in SQL ".myql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Also you need not retrieve the same data if there are records found > 0, you can utilize the previously queried resource to fetch the required data to return short URL.

Comment: Thanks for you're answer I just choose to re-write the entire thing from clean list in PDO. Works fine now

Answer (score 0):

Because of discontinuation of mysql_* I re-written the entire thing in PDO works fine now.